# With an Ancestry.com account do I have access to other sites they own?

Tags: records, ancestry.com, website, subscription

From [this article](http://techcrunch.com/2012/04/25/ancestry-com-acquires-archives-com-from-inflection-for-100-million/) I understand Ancestry.com owns other sites like Genealogy.com, Fold3.com, Rootsweb.com, Footnote.com and (recently) Archives.com.

Given that I'm a paying customer of Ancestry.com, do I have access to any of the other sites under that subscription?

Comment: Stack Exchange supports a lot of 3rd-party project teams to provide technical support for their sub-communities through our sites (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project). But this is really a specific  customer support issue for Ancestry.com and better asked in their support channels.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the website. Ancestry's pay sites usually need their own sign in and their free sites (Roootsweb and Mundia) can use the Ancestry account info.

Answer (score 1):

Fold3 requires a separate reg fee.